# Eth0 used for incoming and eth1 used outgoing connections NGINX configuration?

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm using AWS instance and I have two ENI eth0 (192.168.1.100) and eth1 (192.168.1.200), usage of the ETH0 network interface for accepting the incoming connections from clients to NGINX(TCP) and an ETH1 network interface for outgoing connections from NGINX to destination( another instance TCP connection). Is it possible to do that?

[image: NGINX LB setup with dual ENI]

Comment: Useless, but possible.

Comment: they are the same subnet ? 1.100 and 1.200 ?

Comment: Yes, both IPs are on the same subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, yes, it's possible:

```
proxy_bind 192.168.1.200;
```

[Documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_bind)

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander, Thanks. Its working fine with configuration below,

```
upstream my_tcp_connect {
    server 192.168.1.300:9000;
        zone tcp_mem 512k;
     }

server {
        tcp_nodelay on;
        listen 9000 backlog=409600 so_keepalive=30m::10 reuseport;
        proxy_pass my_tcp_connect;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
        proxy_buffer_size 512k;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/tcp_error.log info; # nginScript debug logging
proxy_bind 192.168.200; 
}
```

I found some connections established from the NGINX instance,

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.200:59396       192.168.300:9000        ESTABLISHED 3046/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 192.168.200:58680       192.168.300:9000        ESTABLISHED 3049/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 192.168.100:9000       192.30.40.14:53110     ESTABLISHED 3048/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 192.168.100:9000       192.30.40.14:54924     ESTABLISHED 3049/nginx: worker
```

TCP Connection instance:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.300:9000        192.168.200:58632       ESTABLISHED 1997/tcp_connect
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.300:9000        192.168.200:59160       ESTABLISHED 1997/tcp_connect
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.300:9000        192.168.200:59360       ESTABLISHED 1997/tcp_connect
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.300:9000        192.168.200:59298       ESTABLISHED 1997/tcp_connect
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Please accept my answer if you find it correct.

Comment: Alexander, yes I did. :)

Comment: i see you have proxy_bind 192.168.200; - should it be proxy_bind 192.168.1.200; ?